# run a specific line from a csv file depending on user input

Tags: python, csv, input, keyword

How do you run a specific line from a csv file depending on user input.
My code asks the user to input the problem with their phone, if the user inputs water has spilled the keyword water or spilled will be identified and a   solution stored in the csv will be printed. However i stored many solutions there for different keywords.

Comment: The lines in `keywords.txt` are alternating between keywords and solutions, right? Additionally, I would recommend using json as a better way of storing information: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: @BurningKarl can you check out my other question

Comment: @stovfl can you check out my other question

Comment: @sufiya: Don't see any **other question**. Why have you deleted your `code`, bring it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First re-write your dataset as:

```
'turn', 'on', 'off'
put it on charger
'small', 'text'
go on settings.
...
```

Then search for the problem and print the next line.

```
problems = input("What is the problem?")

with open("/path/myfile.csv") as myfile:
    file = iter(myfile.readlines())
    for line in file:
        if any(word in line for word in problems.split()):
            print(next(file))
            break
```

Comment: thank you!!! is there anyway that the keywords 'off' for example be detected from a sentence. when i type in a sentence including the keyword off the program does not work. if i type in off by itself it works perfectly fine though :) @Tasos

Comment: Glad it works for you! In order to work with a given sentence, an idea would be to split the sentence into words and then search for each word independently. You could replace the `if problems ...` line with `if any(word in line for word in problems.split()):`

Comment: an error comes up. it says problem is not defined @Tasos

Comment: Then you probably did a spelling error while copy parting. It's `problems` not `problem` :)

Comment: if any(word in line for word in problems.split()):
    input("What is the problem?") <--- i copied and pasted + i indented it on my program correctly however it still does not work

Comment: I suspect you just added the line I gave you at the beginning of the code. You should instead replace the previous IF statement with it. I will edit the code in my answer so you can copy it from there.

Comment: thank you it works now but only for 'turn', 'on' .... when i type in water a solution does not appear even though i added it to the same notepad file in the same format.

Comment: Can you update your question with the textfile that you use now? This is most probably an issue with the format.

Comment: Okay, here is the problem. If you ask for example "I spilled water" it will search for "I", "spilled" and "water". It will find "I" in an answer you have in your text file (e.g. `If it says unavailable...` ) and it will print the next line. The next line is blank, so that means that it will print nothing. So in order to work properly you should use only the keywords, and they should NOT appear in the answers! This is not my code's fault, but a bad design of how you want to do it.

Comment: it works!!! i'm sorry i placed the files in two different places. thank you for all the help @Tasos

Comment: Good! If my solution answers your question, please accept it :)

Comment: btw i have a solution which includes a keyword and it works PERFECT!! :) @Tasos

Comment: is there any way you could store the keywords and solutions on spreadsheet excel

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. You can open the .csv file with the MS-Excel and just convert it into whatever form you like.

Answer (score 2):

If your problems/solutions are written in the file this way:

```
Problems1\nSolution1\nProblems2\nSolution2
```

which gives:

```
Problems1
Solution1
Problems2
Solution2
```

you can try this code:

```
problem = input ('What is your problem ? ')

with open ('keywords.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    text = myfile.read()

list_of_problems_and_solutions = text.split('\n')

for i in range (0, len(list_of_problems_and_solutions )-1, 2):
    if problem in list_of_problems_and_solutions [i]
    print (list_of_problems_and_solutions [i + 1])

>>> What is your problem ? Problems1
Solution1
```

The `list_of_problems_and_solutions` will be someting like `['Problems1', 'Solution1', 'Problems2', 'Solution2' ]`
The `for i in range (0, len(list_of_problems_and_solutions )-1, 2):` function will go through the list from index 0 to the end, with a step of 2.
As you see, when I type `Problems1` as my problem, Python returns `Solution1`. You only have to replace with your keywords/solutions

Comment: Be careful with your `i += 1`. You can easily check that `for i, line in enumerate(["a", "b", "c", "d"]): print(i, end=" "); i += 1` gives `0 1 2 3` and not `0 2`

Comment: Right, range function is more appropriate here

Comment: Please change your description as well, because reading about `i += 1` in your description without seeing it in the actual code is confusing. Also `liste` is not defined here, change it to `list_of_problems_and_solutions`

Comment: Oops sorry, I do it

Comment: @Guil23 can you check my other question out plz